# Reply to received XMPP messages with M10

Tags: accounts, m10, xmpp

I have manually setup an XMPP account in my M10 tablet using mc-tool and I can receive XMPP messages without problems. However I cannot answer them because it doesn't have an SIM card:

Will this be possible in the future?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: The M10 does not have the capacity to hold a SIM card.  There is no hardware for it.  If you are receiving XMPP messages, then I'd assume you're using WiFi, in which case you should be able to reply via WiFi.

Comment: Hi. You are right.  However I have been checking the qml code for the messaging app and it always checks for a celular account before sending each reply.... and asks for a SIM card to be inserted. If there is a plan to remove this checks then my problem would be solved....Regards.